# nodejs toString ascii prints garbage as compared to python crypt

Tags: python, node.js, encryption, crypt

I'am trying to print sha512 based password which is generated in linux /etc/shadow.

While printing buffer from result of below function prints the garbage at console.

```
let crypto = require('crypto')
crypto.pbkdf2Sync('$6$qVcwPAy6', 'hello', 0, 86, 'sha512').toString('ascii')
```

I have tried ascii,binary,hex, utf8 etc. but nothing is in comparable to python function result charcters encoding.

`'\u0018#(\u0005\u0000?"f\u0018(R3ef\u0007\\\u001cD,&B|d\u0010f g\u0006\n7\u0010&K.2\u0006S,lM8N\'\fs/H+\u001fwz-%_\b)\u0016[%Y@\u0012Qt2Rg\fz\ty740\u0015\u0015U|\u0013a\u0004@?'`

In python using sha512, it prints nicely on console.

```
import crypt
crypt.crypt('hello','$6$qVcwPAy6')
```

`'$6$qVcwPAy6$7fMDelBgb8d7/95W5VKUftBAuKR2GM2EhPaoUYz6IdscWKcc9AOJ.heKQUmsZuVVocXTS8aMVzD9UywfiyASh0'`

Comment: The python output is base64 encoded. crypt.crypt and crypto.pbkdf2 are not directly comparable anyway.

Comment: I have perception that at end of base64 result there is "=" sign but in python result it doesnot exist.